# Anime story. Monster and monster-hunter become unlikely friends due to a time distortion

Tags: story-identification, anime

I believe the story came from some sort of anime. There was a monster and I think a hunter/hero. The monster destroys some villages or something. So then, the hero chases after the monster to kill it. However, a lot of time elapses as the hero pursues the monster.

Because so much time has passed, the monster is the only one who remembers the hero and the hero is the only one who tried to come close to the monster. They sort of end up being friends due to their circumstances.

Comment: This sounds look a cool story! Can you remember anything else about it, like what the monster looked like?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like [Ushio and Tora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushio_and_Tora/), but it seems unlikely, since in this anime the hunter is a contemporary boy who finds a monster trapped in his house.
However, he can transform himself into a samurai-like warrior because of a magic spear and eventually becomes friend with the monster.

[image]